# How can react-router hold current component until next component is ready?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, react-router

Does anyone know how I can make `react-router` behave like Youtube and Instagram, by holding the current component with top progress bar until the next one makes its calls to the API? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by 'holds on to'? What makes you believe they are holding on to a component? Is it the loading spinner? [Is it the 'skeleton' placeholder?](https://i.imgur.com/fgc7TLU.png)

Comment: no i mean, like when you press a link it shows a top progress bar until the next route is ready

Comment: Then maybe you should look for some online tutorials to learn how react works before moving on such problems.

Comment: I know how react works but I am stuck on this issue

Comment: There must be a npm library or a third-party component, have you found any?

Comment: no, I have not.

Comment: You can use [react-topbar-progress-indicator](https://github.com/MoOx/react-topbar-progress-indicator) .. [Demo found here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rw156kk8km)

Comment: iv seen that before, it doesnt hold the current component. until the promise resolves

Comment: There is no 'magic' solution for this. You should be able to code that logic yourself.

Comment: so how do I do this then please

Comment: (1/2) You could start by researching. In just 15 minutes I have found a ton of resources that you could use to test.

Comment: (2/2) [See this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4407) thread... as well as [this example](https://rr4-preload-szmnvdgody.now.sh/) they provide using [this code](https://gist.github.com/goshakkk/a9df8238f43e4ad71f6ae4034482d509) or [this example](https://rr4-async-transition.surge.sh/data_refresh) with [this code](https://github.com/Velenir/rr4-async-transition/blob/master/app/components/Example.jsx) It is going to be a process in which you test things - there is no "easy button" for something like this.

Comment: this actually helped, thanks